# Codeception + PhantomJS: how to open a new tab and switch to it

Tags: php, phantomjs, codeception

I have an Acceptance Test with Codeception. PhantomJS is configured as my Webdriver. On my page, I have a link that has `target="_blank"` . The problem is, when I instruct Codeception to click on it, it does not focus on the newly opened tab. Hence my test fails.

Code:

```
$I->click('My Link that opens new tab');
```

What I have tried:

```
$I->switchToWindow('Title of my new window'); // doesn't work
$I->see('Some text in my new tab'); // also doesn't work
```

My acceptance.suite.yml:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
       - WebDriver
       - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost'
            browser: 'phantomjs'
            port: 5555
            window_size: '1024x768'
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution, in case there is some other suffering developer soul out there:

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function (\Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver $webdriver) {
$handles = $webdriver->getWindowHandles();
$lastWindow = end($handles);
$webdriver->switchTo()->window($lastWindow);
```

});